# ABCPdf Can't load image from project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, abcpdf9

I am currently having a problem with loading images from my .net MVC project onto a PDF with ABCPdf. I have made sure that the path to the image is correct.

This is the line that adds it to the PDF:

```
theDoc.AddImageFile(<path-to-image>);
```

The error I get back simply reads:

```
Unable to read file
```

Does anybody know what the problem may be?

Comment: Have you scrutinized the relative/absolute path difference? Resolving a relative to absolute is often what's needed. Just because the relative path looks right to you (assuming that's what it is) doesn't mean the `AddImageFile` method necessarily knows where to look.

Comment: I think I have figured out why it isn't working. It seems that within my test project, my base directory is the <project>Test folder.

Comment: That's why I mentioned resolving to an absolute. The general best practice for web stuff is to relative URL everything and when you need to get an absolute URL use Server.MapPath. It doesn't matter where it lives. You'll get a valid absolute path every time.